# Is $f(z) = |z^2 - z|$ nowhere analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis

Is $f(z) = |z^2 - z|$ nowhere analytic? I've tried to use the Cauchy Riemann equations but the expression becomes difficult to solve.

$z^2-z = x^2-x-y^2 + i(2xy-y)$

$|z^2-z| = \sqrt{(x^2-x-y^2)^2 + (2xy-y)^2}$

The imaginary part is $0$, so we differentiate the above with respect to $x$ and equate to $0$.

Then, $\frac{1}{2}((x^2-x-y^2)^2 + (2xy-y)^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\cdot [2(x^2-x-y^2)(2x-1) + 2(2xy-y)(2y)] = 0$

The expression becomes difficult.

Also, here is another function $f(z) = |x^2-y^2| + 2i|xy| $, $z=x+iy$.

Comment: Why did you not succeed with CR equations? It would help if you posted what you have tried so far, because I think CR equations should not be that difficult to check...

Comment: Are they that difficult to solve? As your function has no imaginary part, the Cauchy-Riemann equations say that your function's x-derivative and y-derivative must equal zero. Can you write that out?

Comment: I have included my workings

Comment: You can immediately see from the CR equations that any holomorphic function which takes only real values must be constant.

Comment: @MartinR Some care need to be taken with that approach though as the question was that to show that the function is nowhere analytic (not only that it's not everywhere analytic).

Comment: @skyking: That argument can be applied *locally.*

Comment: @MartinR I meant that, but if you're not careful you might forget to do that...

Comment: How about the second function, $f(z) = |x^2-y^2| + 2i|xy|$ where $z=x+iy$?

Comment: @yh016 There you simply divide the absolute into regions, you have $\nabla |x^2-y^2| = \pm\nabla (x^2-y^2)$ and $\nabla 2|xy| = \pm\nabla (2xy)$ depending on the region (except when $x^2-y^2=0$ or $xy=0$ respectively). If $x^2 > y^2$ and $xy>0$ for example the function becomes $f(z) = x^2 - y^2 + 2i xy = (x+iy)^2$ which is analytic. So that function is analytic somewhere (but also non-analytic somewhere)...

Comment: I see, I will post my workings here soon!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By taking out the factor $(2x - 1)$, the equation you wrote down simplifies to
$$
x = \frac{1}{2} \quad \text{or} \quad y^2 = x - x^2 .
$$
Similarly, writing down the derivative with respect to $ y$ and setting equal to zero gives
$$
y = 0 \quad \text{or} \quad 2y^2 = -2x^2 + 2x - 1 .
$$
Now solve four systems, each time taking one of the two equations of the first line and one of the two equations of the second line. This gives solutions
$$
(\frac{1}{2}, 0), (0, 0), (1,0)
$$
Thus the only points at which the functions might be differentiable are the above points, since satisfying the Cauchy-Riemann equations is a necessary condition. That your function is nowhere analytic is immediate, as being analytic is an open property and no non-empty open set will be a subset of the above three points. Alternatively, as Martin R noted, an analytic real-valued function can only satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations if it is constant on an open set, which your function is not.

If you want to know whether the function is differentiable in any of the given points, you can try to evaluate the limit in the definition of the derivative by hand in these three points. Dig up your multivariable calculus notes for this.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll try the question again. How about the second function where CR equations cannot be used?

Comment: How do you mean, "cannot be used"? Your teacher does not allow you to?

Comment: My bad, I didn't thought of splitting the $\mathbb{R}^2$ plane first.

Answer (score 0):

I also read this question on the Snider's book. And here was my solution.

Call $u$ and $v$ the real part and the imaginary part of $f$.
Then $v$ is null. If $f$ is analytic in some ball $B$, the Cauchy-Riemann equations give us $u_x=u_y=v_x=v_y=0$, which then implies $f'=0$ on $B$. This yields a contradiction since $f$ is not $\mathbb{R}$-differentiable at $0$ and $1$ and since $f$ has a non null $\mathbb{R}$-differential at $z$ when $z \notin \{0,1/2,1\}$, by the chain rule : $\mathbb{R}$-differential of $z \mapsto z^2-z$ at $z_0$ is $h \mapsto (2z_0-1)h$ and the $\mathbb{R}$-differential of $w \mapsto |w|$ at $w_0 \ne 0$ is $h \mapsto \Re((\overline{z}/|z|)h)$.

Comment: By "some place D" you mean "some domain $D$"?